# Need a web-embedded editor that doesn't save in HTML

Tags: javascript, client-side, markdown, bbcode

Our clients are able to edit some text on our "admin" web site, which then displays to their customers on another "client" web site.  They now want the ability to add mark-up like bold, italic, underline (and combinations of the above) plus links to web pages.  Unfortunately, because we use a web framework that passes the stored text through a XSLT decoder (don't ask), we can't just save their changes as HTML because otherwise it will screw up the XSLT step.

I was thinking that what I need is something like a Markdown or BBCode editor that stores the text in the database with the Markdown or BBCode markup, and then some javascript on the client side that interprets the markup into HTML.  Is there such a thing?

Comment: Can you just escape the markup code, then unescape it before it's displayed to the user?  Converting it into another markup system just to convert it back to html seems unnecessary.

Comment: Does the XSLT decoder not ignore CDATA elements?

Comment: Unfortunately, the XSLT decoder appears to do something to the CDATA elements, so `<DESCRIPTION><![CDATA[Word <b>bold</b>]]></DESCRIPTION>` ends up being `<p>Word &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;</p>` by the time the user sees it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two:

http://attacklab.net/showdown/

http://github.com/openlibrary/wmd (similar or the one SO's markdown editor is based on)